# SD card cloning using the dd command

Tags: sd-card, clone

I am trying to clone an SD card which may contain a number of partitions, some of which Ubuntu cannot recognize. Generally, I want to clone the whole volume, not only some partition. So, I mount the SD card and see something like this in the Log viewer:

```
kernel: [  262.025221]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2

alex@u120432:~$ ls /dev/sdc*
/dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdc2
```

Since I want to copy the whole disk, I execute:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=sdimage.img bs=4M
```

File sdimage.img, 7.9 GB (7,944,011,776 bytes) is created (SD card is 8 GB). Now I mount another SD card and execute:

```
dd if=sdimage.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

The problem is that the second dd command hangs on some stage, and never succeeds. After this, I cannot reboot or shut down computer, and I need just to switch power off.

Is this the correct approach? Maybe there is another way to clone an SD card?

OS: [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin), 32 bit.

Comment: Can you mount created img file and see if it is created correctly?

Comment: @MilanTodorovic - how can I do this?

Comment: If I remember correctly: mount -o loop sdimage.img /path/to/mount. Then check to see if you can browse img file correctly.

Comment: @MilanTodorovic: I tried sudo mount -o sdimage.img /dev/mydisk and got: mount: can't find /dev/mydisk in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab Possibly I need to create some dev entry before. Can you post this as answer with some details? Thanks.

Comment: Try with sudo mount -o loop sdimage.img /dev/mydisk (you forgot loop after -o)

Comment: @MilanTodorovic: mount: mount point /dev/mydisk does not exist (this time with loop)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6692/discussion-between-milan-todorovic-and-alex-farber)

Comment: you should not be using dd on mounted devices.  unmount all the partitions first, then your command should work.

Comment: @ubfan1 - thanks, your suggestion works. Please post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Is the value of `bs=4M` need to be the same value during the copy process?

Comment: If you don't insist on using `dd`, then you can run the Gnome Disks, and that one let's you mount/unmount at will, and create an image file form any device.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should not be using dd on mounted devices. unmount all the partitions first, then your command should work.

Comment: why is the opposite for me? I've Ubuntu 12.10 and the command has works only with partitions monted...

Comment: @Velthune Are you sure about that? If so, I'd suggest making your own question.

Answer (score 83):

Insert the original SD card and check the name of the device (usually `mmcblkX` or `sdcX`):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You might see:

```
Device         Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *       2048  2099199  2097152    1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      2099200 31116287 29017088 13.9G 83 Linux
```

In my case the SD card is `/dev/mmcblk0` (the `*p1` and `*p2` are the partitions).

Now you have to unmount the device:

```
sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0
```

Now to create an image of the device:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=~/sd-card-copy.img bs=1M status=progress
```

This will take a while.

Once it's finished, insert the empty SD card. If the device is different (USB or other type of SD card reader) verify its name and be sure to unmount it:

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0
```

Write the image to the device:

```
sudo dd if=~/sd-card-copy.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M status=progress
```

The write operation is much slower than before.

Comment: when copying big amounts of data you should set a bigger than default blocksize, otherwise you may have to wait very long.
`sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=~/sd-card-copy.img bs=4M`

Comment: Can we copy the resultinf `sd-card-copy.img` on the same card itself ?

Comment: One thing that is really annoying of the `dd` command is that there is no output by default. 

You can change that by adding `status=progress` at the end of your command
Therefore it would become: `sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/media/data/sd-card-copy.img status=progress`

Comment: Note: in my case the name of the device was `sdc`, not `sdcX` like written in this answer because `sdcX` was used for the partitions, for example partitions were named `sdc1` and `sdc2`. At least this answer helped me to make the `dd` command work by using `/dev/sdc` instead of `/dev/sdc1`.

Answer (score 17):

I am using dd tool to clone usb sticks with multiple partitions, here is my command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

*notrunc* - do not truncate the output file 
*noerror* - continue after read errors

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes it does, many of us use those 4-in-1 type adapters.

Answer (score 11):

dd is fine, but I prefer `cat /dev/sdc/ > ~/backup.iso`
If you want to put it on an SD card again, just run `cat ~/backup.iso > /dev/sdc`

Comment: Both SD are 8 GB. cat can be used to make SD image, but to make another SD I should use dd, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps which worked for me on Ubuntu to **restore** the image file (`~/raspberrypi2.img` in my case) back to a new SD card (inspired heavily by Alon's reply above):

1. Insert the micro SD card via the card reader.
2. Open the Disks app.
3. Quick format the whole card (not a specific partition).
4. Close Disks.
5. Open terminal and execute:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

Relevant output (which showed there were no partitions due to the quick format of the whole card):

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0x6957f2f2
```

---

```
sudo dd if=~/raspberrypi2.img of=/dev/sdb
```

This step takes a few good minutes (even on USB3). **Make sure to not interrupt it by any operation which will invoke mounting** (opening the Files or Disks apps).

Thanks for everyone's answers.